# wordpress custom meta box update button (get_submit_button)

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use WordPress get)submit_button() to create some buttons on my plugin page to delete meta keys

i used

```
get_submit_button( __( 'Delete' ), "delete:the-list:meta-{$entry['meta_id']}::_ajax_nonce=$delete_nonce deletemeta", "deletemeta[{$entry['meta_id']}]", false, array( 'tabindex' => '6' ) );
```

have also created new nonce code for that.

but im getting - you have no permissions or something like that

how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_submit_button

The second argument is incorrect.
And the because of that the others are also incorrect

Comment: well, this code that i pasted is the default wordpress post template so it is definatly not wrong, either way the codex doesn't s ay much ...

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how your plugin is setup, 
but what I did was to create my form, for deleting anything include the nonce

```
<input type="hidden" name="mybox_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__));?>" />
```

include this within my form, then just create your submit button manually,
submit the form as normal, then using your code, check for the form being submitted

ie:

```
<?php
// using another hidden field within the form
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='remove')){
    $post_meta_key = $_POST['meta_key'];
    $post_meta_value = $_POST['metavalue'];
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade">Post meta deleted.</div>';
}
?>
```

hopefully this helps you out a little

Marty

Comment: well this can surly work , but i preffer using the built in ajax methods on the admin-ajax if possible

Answer (score 0):

solved it...

all that was needed was an extra nonce field

```
wp_nonce_field( 'change-meta', '_ajax_nonce', false, false );
```

so my code looks like:

```
$delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'delete-meta_' . $meta_id );
$output.=get_submit_button( __( 'Delete' ), "delete:the-list:meta-{$meta_id}::_ajax_nonce=$delete_nonce deletemeta", "deletemeta[{$meta_id}]", false, array( 'tabindex' => '6' ) );
$output.=wp_nonce_field( 'change-meta', '_ajax_nonce', false, false );
```

and .... its working :-)